# Remove symfony plugin permanently

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-plugins

i have a strange problem with removing symfony plugin.

I've installed **sfSimpleCommentPlugin** but after realizing that it's not working, i've run uninstall command:

```
php symfony plugin:uninstall sfSimpleCommentPlugin
```

The plugin was successfully uninstalled...but! Now, when i'm running a `php symfony doctrine:build --all` command, i'm getting:

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/bajki/workspace/vimsnip/app/plugins/sfSimpleCommentPlugin/lib/model/doctrine/PluginsfSimpleComment.class.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/bajki/workspace/vimsnip/app/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/autoload/sfSimpleAutoload.class.php on line 123

and few similar errors. And now i'm asking - why this command line tool want's to use **sfSimpleCommentPlugin** files to anything? I've uninstalled it few seconds ago...

Am i doing something wrong? How to remoev this plugin permanently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok it's solved!
All you need to do is to remove `sfSimpleCommentPlugin` folder from `app/lib/model/doctrine` and `app/lib/form/doctrine`